# Failed to get FIS auth token on emulator

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, browserstack

Im using firebase for sending notification.

my version of firebase-messages is:

```
implementation ("com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.0.0")
```

I configure my firebase with  `google-service.json`

The weird issue that when I run my app on the emulator on `browserstack` I get this error:
    `Failed to get FIS auth token` and `java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.google.firebase.installations.FirebaseInstallationsException`

it seems it comes from the installation

but when I run it on physical android device I don't get the error and I succeed to get Token... I checked only on one physical device.In addition I checked on like 10 different emulators devices (include my physical device just on emulator) and they all show the same error.

I tried to change the `firebase-messaging` to version `20.1.0` but it didn't change anything...
I don't understand what might be the issue for that especially that it worked before and I didn't change anything and why it happens only on emulator and not on physical device

Answer (score 0):

> Solution 1

1. If you made any changes inside the firebase console - Download and update `google-services.json` file from firebase console.

> Solution 2

1. If You are using a `Real device` Check your Internet connection.
2. If you are using android studio `Emulator` - Establish an internet connection by resetting the emulator.

   2.1. Open `Tools -> AVD manager`

[image: Step 2.1]

2.2. Wipe Data of the emulator
[image: Wipe Data of the emulator 2.2]

3. Run Project using fresh emulator.